# What is the best way to calculate maximum and minimum values for one list, for each distinct value of another list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, for-loop

Say I have three lists of paired numeric data in Python. The lists are for the day of year (number between 1-365), the hour of day (number between 0-24), and the corresponding temperature at that time. I have provided example lists below:

```
day_of_year = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]      #day = Jan 1 in this example
hour_of_day = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24]
temperature =[23.1,22.0,24.1,26.5,23.8,40.1,32.7,41.3,29.4,36.4,22.0,24.1]
```

I have these hourly paired data for a location for an entire year (I've just shown simplified lists above). So for each day I have 24 `day_of_year` values (that are just the same number repeated, in this example the day = 1) and 24 `temperature` values since they're hourly data. I'm trying to design a for loop that allows me to iterate through these data to calculate and use the maximum and minimum temperature for each day of year, since another function that my code uses needs to call on those values. What would be the best way to reference all the temperature values where `day_of_year` are the same to calculate max and min temperatures for every day.

I have a function that takes the following inputs:

`minimum_temp_today, minimum_temp_tomorrow, maximum_temp_today, maximum_temp_yesterday`

I need to figure out how to pull out those values for each day of the year. I am looking for suggestions on the best way to do this. Any suggestions/tips would be super appreciated!

Comment: have you considered putting this into a dataframe so you can groupby the day and extract min and max? would you like an answer showing how to do that?

Comment: temperature list has all temperatures for all hours for all days? All in one list?

Comment: Hi all, my apologies for the delayed response. @gold_cy Yes, that would be very helpful. Do you think that option would work better than using classes? I am even less familiar with classes, but that is another idea that came up on the internet while I was searching for a solution here.

Comment: @BrainDead yes, temperature is one huge list

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could approach this, depending on what data structures you want to use. If you don't care about when the min and max occur, then personally I'd do something like this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

daily_temps = defaultdict(list)
for day, value in zip(day_of_year, temperature):
     daily_temps[day].append(value)

ranges = dict()
for day, values in temps.items():
    ranges[day] = (min(values), max(values))
```

Basically, you're constructing an intermediate `dict` that maps each day of the year to a list of all the measurements for that day. Then in the second step you use that `dict` to create your final `dict` which maps each day of the year to a `tuple` which is the minimum and maximum value recorded for that day.

Comment: thank you! I just tried this and it works. As you stated this generates a tuple with the min and max values for each day. I would like to have the data in a list since I need to iterate through them in a function to calculate something else. I imagine making a for loop like, `for min, max in zip(daily_min,daily_max):  `

Comment: would you suggest simply converting the tuples to lists, or would you structure your answer differently to generate a list for daily min and max temperatures?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pandas` which does this quite efficiently. I am using `pandas 1.0.1`. We end up using [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) for this task.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'day_of_year': day_of_year, 'hour_of_day': hour_of_day, 'temperature': temperature})

print(df)

    day_of_year  hour_of_day  temperature
0             1            2         23.1
1             1            4         22.0
2             1            6         24.1
3             1            8         26.5
4             1           10         23.8
5             1           12         40.1
6             1           14         32.7
7             1           16         41.3
8             1           18         29.4
9             1           20         36.4
10            1           22         22.0
11            1           24         24.1


df.groupby('day_of_year').agg( \
    min_temp=('temperature', 'min'),
    max_temp=('temperature', 'max')) \
  .reset_index() \
  .to_dict('records')

[{'day_of_year': 1, 'min_temp': 22.0, 'max_temp': 41.3}]
```

Now suppose we have data for more than one day.

```
   day_of_year  min_temp  max_temp
0          1.0      22.0      41.3
1          2.0      24.0      26.0
2          3.0      24.5      42.3


grouped = df.groupby('day_of_year') \
            .agg(min_temp=('temperature', 'min'),
                 max_temp=('temperature', 'max')) \
            .reset_index()


tmrw = grouped.shift(-1) \
              .rename( \
                columns={'min_temp': 'min_temp_tmrw', 
                         'max_temp': 'max_temp_tmrw'}) \
              .drop('day_of_year', axis=1)

pd.concat([grouped, tmrw], axis=1).to_dict('records')

[{'day_of_year': 1.0,
  'min_temp': 22.0,
  'max_temp': 41.3,
  'min_temp_tmrw': 24.0,
  'max_temp_tmrw': 26.0},
 {'day_of_year': 2.0,
  'min_temp': 24.0,
  'max_temp': 26.0,
  'min_temp_tmrw': 24.5,
  'max_temp_tmrw': 42.3},
 {'day_of_year': 3.0,
  'min_temp': 24.5,
  'max_temp': 42.3,
  'min_temp_tmrw': nan,
  'max_temp_tmrw': nan}]
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to do all of this! I just sat down and worked through all your code to make sure I understand it all... everything was pretty easy to follow! The only thing I'm trying to figure out is how to store the min and max temperatures in a list. I want to be able to iterate through the min and max temperatures, and also plot them. The way they get stored here doesn't allow me to do that. Do you have any idea how to do this? Also, could you please explain what the `to_dict('records')` code does? Thanks in advance - Lauren

Comment: you will have to iterate over the list of dictionaries and extract what you need. it should be fairly simple to do, even for a beginner. please try it yourself.

Comment: `test_df = pd.DataFrame({'DOY': DOY, 'TIME': TIME, 'Ta_sun': Ta_sun})


mins_maxes=[test_df.groupby('DOY').agg( \
    min_temp=('Ta_sun', 'min'),
    max_temp=('Ta_sun', 'max')) \
  .reset_index()] #\
  #.to_dict('records')]


daily_mins= mins_maxes['min_temp']

May1=[(k,mins_maxes(min_temp[k==120])) for k in mins_maxes]`  gives me the type error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str". Is there anyway to pull the data out from here as a list of integers? @gold_cy

Comment: just use a list comprehension. for example to get the `mins` you can do `[item['min_temp'] for item in mins_maxes]` and so forth for the other columns. you could also not convert to a dict by removing the `to_dict['records']`. you can simply do `mins_maxes.min_temp.values`. also remove the brackets around the groupby statement